# How to add Days in a islamic or HijriDate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have two text boxes.One is for taking **StartDate** from a islamic calender,so i am using jQuery Calendars Datepicker.
The **ExpireDate** textbox will automatically 60days from **StartDate**.so i am writing the logic in Onclose event of datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ShowCalender();
});
function ShowCalender() {
    var calendar = $.calendars.instance('islamic');
    $('[id$=TxtOrderDate]').calendarsPicker({
        calendar: calendar,
        onClose: function (dates) {
            var expiryDate = new Date(dates);
            var x = 60;
            expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + x);               
            document.getElementById('<%=TxtExpirationDate.ClientID%>').value = expiryDate;
        },
        showTrigger: '<img src="../../../_layouts/15/1033/Saudia/Images/calender.png" alt="Popup" class="trigger img">'

    });
}
```

but here the ExpireDate fill with Date **Sun Apr 24 03:00:00 UTC+0300 1436**,which is a gregorian date.
expiredate mustbe the islamic Date.

How to add specific number of Days in FromDate?
Please help.

Comment: please ask a question

Comment: @Bot my question is how to add days in a isalamic date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should perform date operations (add date) in Gregorian format and then format back to Islamic date.
[keith-wood.name/calendars](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html)